# The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized error while connecting to Office365

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm getting above error message while connecting to Office365 .

```
  ExchangeService serviceInstance = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
  serviceInstance.Credentials = new WebCredentials("sample@microsoft.com", "Password", "REDMOND"); 
  serviceInstance.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
   foreach (EmailMessage email in serviceInstance.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100)))
     {

     }
```

Both Username and Pwd are correct but still getting issue.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be specifying the domain in

serviceInstance.Credentials = new WebCredentials("sample@microsoft.com", "Password", "REDMOND");

just use the user account upn only (and that maybe different from the Email Address)

serviceInstance.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sample@microsoft.com", "Password");

or try the down-level format

serviceInstance.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domain\user", "Password");

Comment: I tried both mentioned by you, but still getting issue "The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." . I'm able to login to https://outlook.office.com/ using correct credentials  but unable to fetch data from code.

Comment: try testing it with the ewseditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases and https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Comment: Still Issue not yet resolved. Could someone suggest.